# Using injective function to prove relation between image of function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Question:

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function and $C$, $D ⊆ A$
Prove that if $f$ is injective then $f(C) ∩ f(D) \subseteq f(C ∩ D)$.

My attempt:

Let $ y \in f(C) \cap f(D)$ implies $y \in f(C)$  and $y \in f(D)$  which implies $y = f(a)$  for  some $a \in C$  and  $y = f(b)$ for  some  $b\in D$.

I am not sure how to use the fact that $f$ is injective in order to continue.

Comment: No this is not a duplicate. This says something about intersections.

Comment: @math-qed Read the second part of the question and the corresponding [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1131982).

Comment: Ah okay. I'm sorry! Went through it too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you are:

You have $y = f(a) = f(b)$ for $a \in C$ and $b \in D$, so $a = b \in C \cap D$ ($a = b$ by injectivity). This implies that $y = f(a)  \in f(C \cap D)$, as $a \in C \cap D$, which is the result we wanted.

Comment: You actually can show that this is equivalent to injectivity by considering two different singletons whose members are mapped to the same element...