# $\Bbb{Z}$-module of subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ with elementwise scalar multiplication and subset symmetric difference addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers, modules

Consider the elementwise product $A\cdot B = \{ ab: a\in A, b \in B\}$ and let $A \Delta B = (A \setminus B) \uplus (B \setminus A)$ be the symmetric difference of subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$.

We know that the $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Z})$ forms a ring with $+ = \Delta$ and $\cdot = \cap$.

What I want to do is different, and I believe it has been observed before, but I am unable to find the paper that talked about it.

However, let $X = \{x\}, x\neq 0$ and consider $X \cdot Y = $ not $X \cap Y$ but instead, the elementwise product $XY := X \cdot Y = \{ xy: x\in X, y\in Y\}$.

Clearly $xY \Delta xZ = \{ xy : y \in Y, xy \notin xZ \} \uplus \{ xz : z \in Z, xz \notin xY\}$, but $xy \notin xZ \implies y \notin Z$ since if $y \in Z$ then $xy \in xZ$ a contradiction.  Conversely, if $y \notin Z$ then $xy \in xZ \implies xy = xz$ for some $z \in Z \implies x(y-z) = 0 \implies z = y \in Z$ since either $\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain or (if you want to further generalize, $\Bbb{Z}^{\times}$ is a cancellative monoid).

Thus $\{xy: y \in Y, xy \notin xZ \} = x \{y : y\in Y, y\notin Z\} = x (Z \setminus Y)$.  For two disjoint sets $U,V$ we have $x (U \uplus V) = x U \uplus x V$ since $x\cdot$ is a function from $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ and [forward images respect arbitrary unions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1132766/26327) (not even necessarily disjoint).

Thus we have shown that $x(Y + Z) = xY + xZ$ where $+ \Delta$ in any ring of subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ (or a commutative ring).  If $x = 0$ then we have $0(X + Y) = \{0\} \neq 0X + 0Y = \{0\} + \{0\} = \{\}$ whenever $X + Y \neq \{\}$ and $X,Y$ are both non-empty.

---

**Thus my questions are:** is my proof of distributitivity in $(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Z}), \Delta, \cdot)$ valid for $x \neq 0$ valid and how do we formally identify $\{\} = \{0\}$ or in other words remedy the contradiction in the case $x = 0$.

---

Alas $\Delta$ doesn't commute with $\cup$ so we don't (usuing the above methods) have an elementwise ring of subsets, however, we would  have a *boolean* $\Bbb{Z}$-module.  See [symmetric difference properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties) at the bottom.

---

The same construction should apply whenever $R$ is a ring (not necc. commutative) such that either $R$ is an integral domain or $R^{\times}$ is a cancellative monoid.  Then you would be constructing a left (right)-boolean $R$-module.

---

If $I \leqslant R$ is a (left) ideal of $R$, then then $\mathcal{P}(I)$ a (left) $R$-submodule of $\mathcal{P}(R)$.

---

Now for the fun part.  Consider the subsets $X^{(i)} \subset \Bbb{Z}$ such that $X^{(i)} = \{ x_1 \cdots x_i : x_j $ are prime numbers $\}.$

Then we have the property $X^{(i)} X^{(j)} = X^{(i+j)}$ which is almost like what occurs in a [graded ring/module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_module) setting except the $X^{(i)}$ are not abelian groups, in fact they're no where close to one.  Perhaps they might satisfy properties of a graded monoid, but I can't find much info on those that's at my level of understanding.

So, take the set of subsets $M_i = \{ aX^{(i)} : a \in R \}$, then $M_i$ is an boolean abelian subgroup, in fact an $R$-submodule of $\mathcal{P}(R)$.  And so if $R$ is a graded ring then there might be a graded module thing going on.

Comment: I'm thinking you consider the boolean group $\mathcal{P}(R)$ and quotient by $\{0\} - \{\} = \{0\}$ - would that work?  Then the factor group is an $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the issue with $0$, there is a much more serious failure of distributivity: while you have verified the distributive law $x(Y+Z)=xY+xZ$, you have not verified the distributive law $(x+y)Z=xZ+yZ$, and pretty much any examples show that this distributive law fails rather horribly.  So, this definition is not going to give you anything close to a module and there is not any reason to expect that any small modification would work.

(By the way, every abelian group admits a unique $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, so there is not really much point to focusing on defining a scalar multiplication as you have done.  Indeed, the distributive law $(x+y)Z=xZ+yZ$ forces scalar multiplication to always agree with the obvious "repeated addition" definition for any $\mathbb{Z}$-module.)