# Functions of infinite unions equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

There's a problem I can't really wrap my head around, and its this:

Let $f : A → B$ and $A_i \subset A$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that

$f\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\right) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} f(A_{i})$

How would I treat both finding $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$? I would typically go about element chasing, and begin with $y \in f\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\right)$, then there $\exists i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in A_i$ such that $y = f(x)$, and because of generality we get the RHS. I don't feel like this is sufficient reasoning, so could I be given a bit of direction of polishing my reasoning?

Comment: This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131956/image-of-the-union-and-intersection-of-sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear why you "don't feel like this is sufficient reasoning", so I'll write out an answer in detail and maybe that will make it clearer what is the source of this feeling.

$\subseteq$: Suppose $y \in f \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)$.  Then there is an $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ such that $y = f(x)$.  So there is an $i \in [1,\infty)$ such that $x \in A_i$ and so $y \in f(A_i)$.  Since $f(A_i) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i)$, we obtain $y \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i)$.  Therefore, $f \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i)$.

$\supseteq$: Suppose $y \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i)$.  Then there is an $i \in [1,\infty)$ such that $y \in f(A_i)$.  So there is an $x \in A_i$ such that $y = f(x)$.  Since $x \in A_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, we obtain $y \in f\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)$.  Therefore, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i) \subseteq f\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)$.

Comment: Seeing it in full does help, yeah. It should be the same for intersection as long as f in injective, right?

Comment: I think so.  Remember to switch "there exists"s to "for all"s and to use the injectivity to pull back to unique preimages.